# How do I find repeating records In a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a table with almost 20000 records
with columns

```
Id      SubjectId      UniqueId
1        54            1
1        58            2
1        59            3
1        60            4
2        54            5
2        58            6
2        59            7
2        60            8
2        60            9
3        54            10
3        70            11
```

I want to Select those Records Which Are repeating
like
result is Like

```
Id      SubjectId      UniqueId
 2        60            8
 2        60            9
 7        54            15
 7        54            18
 7        54            30
```

Help Me how could I do this

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: i am using MSSQl server 2008r2

Comment: The answers below will work with your version of MSSQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `EXISTS()`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.ID = b.ID AND
                    a.SubjectID = b.subjectID
            GROUP   BY Id, SubjectId
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10f1e/1)

Comment: +1 for the fiddle - that way he can see if it works with his version of SQL

Comment: I personaly prefer instead (Group By and Having) to use (AND
                    a.UniqueId!=b.UniqueId)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize analytic `COUNT()` since you're using **SQL Server 2008**

```
SELECT id, subjectid, uniqueid
  FROM   
(
  SELECT  id, subjectid, uniqueid,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, subjectid) cnt
    FROM  table1
) q
 WHERE cnt > 1
```

or another way

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM   
(
  SELECT  id, subjectid
    FROM  table1
   GROUP  BY id, SubjectId
  HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
) q JOIN table1 t
    ON q.id = t.id
   AND q.subjectid = t.subjectid
```

Output for both queries:

```
| ID | SUBJECTID | UNIQUEID |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  2 |        60 |        8 |
|  2 |        60 |        9 |
|  7 |        54 |       15 |
|  7 |        54 |       18 |
|  7 |        54 |       30 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/923ad/4)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this

fetch only duplicate record

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME as t1 where SubjectId  in (SELECT SubjectId   FROM TABLE_NAME as t2 where t2.Id=t1.Id and t1.UniqueId<>t2.UniqueId) order by Id,SubjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

Count your IDs , if greater then 1 then then select it

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
HAVING  COUNT(id) > 1
```